# What happened to "add to interesting tags"?

Tags: support, status-bydesign, tag-watching

When you hovered over a tag, there used to be an option that said "Add to interesting tags" (or something similar to that).  Now there only seem to be options to subscribe to that tag for email notifications, or for RSS.  Am I missing something?  Is this option available elsewhere?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Click the star on the tag tooltip to add the tag as a favorite.

[image]

Comment: What about a custom RSS feed for those favorites. I build one myself using some tricks, but each time I want to add or remove a tag, it's not easy as it could be. URL could be http://stackechange.org/user/{userid}/questions/favorites/.you get the idea. And i don't want to subscribe to dozen of different feeds. It would be great!

Comment: @pierre this feature already exists on http://stackexchange.com under "Tag Sets"

Comment: Thank you I wasn't aware. I subscribed to so blog, should I sunscribe to another blog to get informed about those nice new features?

Comment: Wow.  That is not obvious at all.  Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

You can add interesting (favorite) tags on the right side of the "home" page.